# How do I use information from Node.js on an index page in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http

I am currently new to the MEAN stack and essentially I have a basic application.

I am running the node server on localhost so the Node.js serves the index page

```
var index = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', index);
```

And the router looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

});

module.exports = router;
```

So nothing fancy, it's an empty router. First I'm trying to understand how this router is serving that HTML page? Shouldn't I have to do a render() or something?

My next question is, how do I take data from the Node.js and serve it to the initial GET request and use that data on the Angular side?

I know another method could be to send another GET request and use the response data and bind it to a scope variable. What I mean by this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.data = [''];

    getData(); //Call getData to go to server and retrieve the data I want

    function getData() {
        $http
            .get('/')
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data;
            });
        });
    }

});
```

Basically, from my point of view, there is 2 GET requests being made. When I go to localhost:3000/ and my HTML page is loaded and then when the controller is loaded in the HTML page (which is done through getData). Is there a way to reduce this to one GET request (preferably in the initial request)?

Comment: "First I'm trying to understand how this router is serving that HTML page? " — I'm failing to understand how it is doing anything at all. When I run the code it says: `ReferenceError: app is not defined`. Is something missing from your [mcve]?

Comment: Why do you want to reduce it to one request? It's a more scalable pattern to keep the serving of the static html seperate from the providing of application data.

Comment: @Quentin It's not minimal, complete, verifiable because there's some code I removed to make it easier to read. If the ReferenceError is from the server side, you might have to add `var app = express()` which uses the express framework.

Comment: @Sahil — You should provide a [mcve]. Presumably the reason it manages to render the page is because of code you didn't include.

Comment: @Belfordz I have no trouble making two request especially since this app is small, but I thought it'd be optimal to only have one.

Comment: @sahil the idea here would be that you could take your static html, serve the files from some static file CDN, and pay very little for a lot. This way your users see the first render of your app quickly, making the perceived load time shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this express docs page about templating engines](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html)

What you would do is give a template instead of html for your index file. First we need to tell our express app what rendering engine we want

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

Now we want to define our index route, where the index route returns our html + data inserted in a particular way.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index', { allThemDatas: { username: 'pleb', password: 'password' } })
})
```

You could rewrite your index file to use a particular templating syntax. ejs is one that would make doing so pretty easy so we will go with that one. We just want to take our original index.html file and add the following into the head or where ever:

```
...
<head>
  <script>
    var userdata = <%= allThemDatas %>;
  </script>
</head>
...
```

From here, you can either just use `window.userdata`, or a more testable angular way of doing this is to use angular constants instead.

```
angular
.module('userdata', [])
.constant("data", <%= allThemDatas %>)
```

As a completely other alternative, by using angular ui-router and using `resolve`'s, you could fetch the data from the server using $http, and the resolve will inject the results of the $http request into your view's controller for you.

Comment: Let's say I have allThemDatas that needs to be binded to a $scope.data variable which needs to be displayed on that HTML page? Wouldn't the ejs template `userdata` and the `$scope.data` conflict? or would I be able to do something like `$scope.data = userdata` in the ejs file by default?

I am starting to think, this would only complicate things and it's a better idea to make the first GET request for your static page and the second GET request for the data.

Comment: It seems from your comments that you want an _easy_ way to get the response from the `GET` request into your view. The `view` -> `controller` -> `service` -> `route` pattern is scalable, meaning, it separates concerns, which is how you want code to be. In the long run, this pattern is easier to test, easier to maintain.

Comment: I think I understand that better now. I think what is happening is `service` -> `route` -> `view` when you initially type in your URL... and I was trying to put `controller` before `view` which doesn't work.

Comment: @ilovecoding Updated to hopefully provide a little more clarity here.

Answer (score 0):

Your node router sets up a route, which your angular service method can make a `GET` request to.

So, to illustrate:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.send("something");
});
```

This actually makes the `GET` request and collects the response, should you choose to do it. As illustrated above, you can send whatever response you want–in this case, the string "something." Think of it as an endpoint.

And in your angular service (not the controller, in my opinion), you could make a `GET` request:

```
app.service('DataService', function(DataService){
    function getData() {
        $http
            .get('/')
            .success(function(data){
                $scope.data = data; // data will be "something"
            });
        });
    }
});
```

This is actually making a request to that endpoint and providing your controller with the response. You may want to use this response in the view or do something with it.

Then, inject this service in your controller like so:

```
app.controller('MyController', ['DataService', function(DataService){
    //...
     DataService.getData().then(function(data){
        // do something with data
     });
```

Comment: I understand the part where if I want to make a GET request that  the route will serve that request with a response that I can use in a service or factory. What I'm confused about is when you type 'localhost:3000' in your browser, the browser sends a GET request but how do I access that initial request? Is there no way to get the response from the very first GET request a client makes? Do you always have to make that second one?

Comment: You have complete control over that as well! When you first start the server, you can tell it what the root path is going to be. `/` is the root path which `localhost:3000` maps to. You can map `localhost` to `/whatever`, if you want.